# How to add exception filtering to MassTransit circuit breaker?

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to add exception filtering to MassTransit circuit breaker. I'd like to use CircuitBreaker only for TimeoutExceptions. Is this possible?

Exception filtering is available for retry/redelivery:

```cs
endpoint.UseRetry(config =>
{
    config.Handle<TimeoutException>();
    config.Interval(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the above example, the message would retry up to ten times, waiting five seconds between attempts, but only if the exception thrown is a `TimeoutException`.

Also, I'd suggest using `UseMessageRetry` instead of `UseRetry` going forward.

You can configure multiple retry filters, each with different policies and filters.

The details of filters is in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#retry-configuration).

Also, make sure the retry configuration is prior to any consumer configuration. Pipelines are built in-order, so order matters.

Comment: Thanks Chis. Didn't notice that ICircuitBreakerConfigurator<TContext> inherits from IExceptionConfigurator

Comment: I also noticed that the OpenBehaviour always rethrows the exception ([source](https://github.com/MassTransit/GreenPipes/blob/3d9a03a4ab1d04bfb69e2446089c33fbbfa4fe6c/src/GreenPipes/Filters/CircuitBreaker/OpenBehavior.cs#L48)) which caused the circuit to open. It can be sometimes confusing especially when you handle multiple types of exceptions or when the exception has some kind of data in the message i.e. an URI. Wouldn't it make sense to wrap the source exception in some kind of CircuitBreakerException: throw new CircuitBreakerException(_exception) ?

Comment: that's a great suggestion, tbh.